# How to copy single array of objects from JSON to Redshift

Tags: json, amazon-redshift

Consider the following data structure in JSON

```
[{"a":1,"b":2}
,{"a":3,"b":4}
,{"a":5,"b":6}
]
```

I want to copy this over using the Redshift COPY command.

I think JsonPath would be needed. The closest I got so far was:

```
{
    "jsonpaths":[
        "$[0].a",
        "$[0].b",
    ]
}
```

However, this only copies over the first row. Anything else I am trying is giving Member is not an object error or not a valid JsonPath.

Answer (score 0):

The sample JSON files shown on [COPY Examples - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_command_examples.html#r_COPY_command_examples-copy-from-json) suggest that each record should be wrapped in `{...}`, with nothing 'above' that level.

Your sample (above) has the whole file wrapped in `[...]`, which is probably causing the issue.

If you remove the `[...]` outer layer, it should work correctly.

Comment: I want to find a solution other than editing the file

Comment: The Amazon Redshift COPY command will not work with a file in that format. You might be able to use **AWS Glue** to transform the file format.